# PHP constructor: private или public?

Tags: php

Какая разница между `public` и `private` в случае с конструктором PHP-класса и на каких основаниях следует выбирать модификатор доступа для конструктора класса?

Comment: Хотите оставить возможность наследования конструктора - делайте public, не хотите - private

Comment: @ilyaplot  а как же сам вызов конструктора из вне?

Comment: @teran А никто не говорит об использовании конструктора. Может класс будет использоваться статически?

Comment: @ilyaplot ну дак я о том и говорю, что суть не только в наследовании, а вообще запрет доступа к нему и запрет создания экземпляров класса вне этого самого класса.

Comment: @teran, Вот насчёт запрета создание экземпляров класса вне класса - самое важное.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Объект класса с `public` конструктором может быть создан в любом месте программы через `new classname`

Объект класса с `private` конструктором может быть создан только в пределах методов этого самого класса (например, в статическом методе)

Поэтому `private` конструктор используется тогда, когда вы хотите чтобы объекты этого класса создавались только определённым образом из одного или нескольких статических методов этого класса и не могли свободно создаваться во внешнем коде. Например, это необходимо для паттерна [одиночка (`singleton`)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

---

Относительно упомянутого в комментариях наследования - существует ещё `protected` уровень. Конструктор возможно наследовать, но всё ещё невозможно создать объект класса извне класса. И важный момент - наследники могут расширять область видимости метода и это не является нарушением контракта класса и наследования. Т.е. класс наследник может объявить свой конструктор публичным, даже если у базового класса конструктор был `private` или `protected`. Нередко при этом делается `final protected` конструктор, из которого вызывается другой метод, который может переопределить наследник - так сохраняется и возможность выполнить какую-то логику инициализации и гарантировать, что конструктор класса не станет публичным

```
class foo {
    public static function create() {
        return new static;
    }
    final protected function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }
    protected function init() {}
}
class bar extends foo {
    protected function init() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
    }
}

bar::create();
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за качественное объяснение!